# Find a very first Fibonacci number which has 1000 digits

Tags: php, ini

this is what i have coded to solve my problem it can produce a 10th digit number quickly, i have changed **php.ini max-execution-time** to **10000** still its not getting an answer in an hour . how can i run this code quickly/sppedly .

```
function fabNumber($n){
    if($n==1 || $n==2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fabNumber($n-2) + fabNumber($n-1);
}

function count_digit($number){
    return strlen($number);
}


$i = 1;
$count = 1;
while( $count != 1000){

    $fab_number = fabNumber($i);
    $count =  count_digit($fab_number);
    //var_dump($fab_number ,$count)."<br>";
    ++$i;
    echo $fab_number . "  index of ". $i ."<br>" ;
}
```

should i use GMP library

```
Edit 1:


  function fabNumber($n){
    if($n==1 || $n==2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return gmp_strval( fabNumber($n-2) )+ gmp_strval(fabNumber($n-1) );
}

function count_digit($number){
    return strlen($number);
}


$i = 1;
$count = 1;
while( $count != 100){

    $fab_number =gmp_strval( fabNumber($i));
    $count =  count_digit($fab_number);
    //var_dump($fab_number ,$count)."<br>";
    ++$i;
    echo gmp_strval($fab_number) . "  index of ". $i ."<br>" ;
}
```

@same slow progress

Comment: You'll need to use gmp library if you want to work with integer values of this size

Comment: what should be the changes either in fabNumber or in while loop ?

Comment: HINT: this method of finding Fib numbers is really inefficient. Try Binet's formula: https://bosker.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/computing-fibonacci-numbers-using-binet%E2%80%99s-formula/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
function getFibonacci() {
    $i = '0';
    $k = '1'; //first fibonacci value
    yield $k;
    while(true) {
        $k = gmp_add($i, $k);
        $i = gmp_sub($k, $i);
        yield $k;
    }
}

foreach(getFibonacci() as $value) {
    if (strlen($value) == 1000) {
        break;
    }
}
echo $value, PHP_EOL;
```

(PHP >= 5.5.0)

Comment: Warning is being generated strlen received at least 1 parameter as String

Answer (score 1):

you can caching numbers to save time because in your version you recalculate all numbers at each iteration

```
$GLOBALS["fabTab"] = array();


function fabNumber($n){
    if($n==1 || $n==2) {
        return "1";
    }

    if (!isset($GLOBALS["fabTab"][$n])) {
        $GLOBALS["fabTab"][$n] = bcadd(fabNumber($n-2), fabNumber($n-1));
    }

    return $GLOBALS["fabTab"][$n];
}

function count_digit($number){
    return strlen($number);
}

$start = time();

$i = 1;
$count = 1;
while( $count != 1000) {
    $fab_number = fabNumber($i);
    $count =  count_digit($fab_number);
    //var_dump($fab_number ,$count)."<br>";
    ++$i;
} 

echo "$fab_number<br/>index of ". $i ."<br>" ;
echo $count . " digits<br>" ;
echo (time() - $start) . " seconds<br>" ;
```

Comment: Thanks you it save my time and let me understand new techniques